# Не могу поставить картинку на фон и кнопку-картинку в jsp страничку- spring maven project в Idea

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, jsp, maven

Задача: добавить фон (картинкой) на страничку + кнопку(картинкой). 
Проблема: В jsp - не работает отображение картинок и фон, которые загружаются картинкой, если взять просто фон - то работает.

AppConfig выглядит так:

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}
```

```html
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers( final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addResourceHandler( "/resources/**" ).addResourceLocations( "/resources/" ).setCachePeriod(180);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css/**").addResourceLocations("resources/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/levelOne/**").addResourceLocations("/images/levelOne");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/levels/**").addResourceLocations("/images/levels");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/mainMenu/**").addResourceLocations("/images/mainMenu");
    }
```

Через css указываю путь к картинкам для background и для кнопки:

```
body {
    background: url(/images/mainMenu/sky.jpg);
}

.buttons {
    background: url(/images/mainMenu/button.png);
}
```

Страничка jsp:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/levels.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Play</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/levels.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<form action="/LevelOne" method="post">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="100%" width="100%" >
                <div align="center" class="buttons">
                    <a href="LevelOne.html">
                        <div id="buttons"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Вот моя структура проекта...правильно? или что то не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так выглядит Facets: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно сделать визуальное отображение картинок в jsp? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: объясните проблему. что у вас не работает? текст из ответа скопируйте в ваш вопрос нажав на ПРАВИТЬ. покажите что у вас лежит в facets

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

resolver.setSuffix(".jsp") поменяй на resolver.setSuffix(".html")

Comment: увы...не работает...получаю HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: а файлы поменяла на  .html ?

Comment: да, поменяла, и меняла - не работает.. и вот я это тоже не понимаю почему.

Comment: а что, собственно, пишет, когда выбивает ошибка?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available
Apache Tomcat/8.0.39. Скриншот: http://prntscr.com/e5cn6f

Comment: Можно скрины классов ?

Comment: AppConfig: http://prntscr.com/e5cum3    Webinitializer: http://prntscr.com/e5cuw0   MyController: http://prntscr.com/e5cv5g

Comment: а где у вас точка входа ( public static void main(String[] args) )? откуда вы запускаете приложение ?

Comment: запускаю через tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

**Тема больше не актуальна. Нашла свою ошибку, была не правильная структура проекта.**

На всякий случай напишу как я пофиксила свою багу, может еще кто то столкнется с такой же проблемой: 
1. У меня заработала такая структура проекта - тоесть папки resources (из стилями) and WEB-INF (из страничками jsp) - должны быть на одном уровне: http://prntscr.com/e5t3bn

2. AppConfig - поменяла пути к папке с ресурсами(стилями)

```html
package ua.kiev.prog;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ua.kiev.prog")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers( final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addResourceHandler( "resources/css/**" ).addResourceLocations( "/resources/css/" );
        registry.addResourceHandler("resources//img/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/img/");

    }

    }
```

3. Поменяла путь к css в head в jsp страничке.

```css
    <link href="/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Зачем вы делаете не рабочие снипеты?